# How To Configure and Download Java JDK in ubuntu for VS code

Tags: java, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I've tried to run vscode in java but the vs code is showing an error of (Not Pointing To JDK).
Is there is any way to run java programs in vs code in ubuntu.

Comment: Of course, a lot of people do that. You can take a look at official docs about java in the VSCode website: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial. Although it's on the windows, but it's similar to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install java from here Install java from here Install java from here Install java from here Install java from here

[https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#:~:text=You%20can%20manually%20install%20the,Code%20for%20the%20first%20time](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#:%7E:text=You%20can%20manually%20install%20the,Code%20for%20the%20first%20time).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to run:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-` and to press TAB several times for available options.

You will then choose a specific jdk.

Some examples:

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-14-jdk`

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-13-jdk`

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk`

Afterwards you can restart VSCode.

Comment: I guess you're trying to do some java development then or you have a java related plugin enabled? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial#_setting-up-visual-studio-code-for-java-development